# How to query a table using result of many-to-many relation with Eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

here is link to my database schema:  [image]

How can I get all topics from the blogs to which the user is subscribed using his id? I use Eloquent ORM.

I have added the following lines to my User model:

```
public function blogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Blog', 'blog_subscriptions');
}
```

And then requested in the controller

```
User::find(1)->blogs;  // User id is hardcoded
```

With that I got all blogs to which the user is subscribed.
And now I am stuck on how to get the topics of those blogs.

Comment: There are a few ways. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added the following lines to my User model: 
public function blogs()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Blog', 'blog_subscriptions');
 }

And then requested in the controller 
User::find(1)->blogs;  // User id is hardcoded
With that I got all blogs to which the user is subscribed
And now I am stuck on how to get the topics of those blogs.

Comment: Sure, but that's just the beginning. Have you read this http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations ?

Comment: Yes, but how could that info help me? It seems to me that I need to add some '->join()' but I am not sure :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming relations:

```
// User
belongsToMany('Blog', 'user_subscriptions')

// Blog
belongsToMany('User', 'user_subscriptions')
hasMany('Topic')

// Topic
belongsTo('Blog')
```

**1 My way, that will work with any relation, no matter how deeply nested:**

```
User::with(['blogs.topics' => function ($q) use (&$topics) {
  $topics = $q->get()->unique();
}])->find($userId);
```

---

**2 Eloquent standard methods:**

```
$topics = Topic::whereHas('blog', function ($q) use ($userId) {
  $q->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('users.id', $userId);
  });
})->get();

// or
$user = User::find($userId);
foreach ($user->blogs as $blog)
{
  $blog->topics; // collection of topics for every single blog
}
```

---

**3 Joins:**

```
$topics = Topic::join('blogs', 'topics.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
     ->join('user_subscriptions as us', function ($j) use ($userId) {
        $j->on('us.blog_id', '=', 'blogs.id')
          ->where('us.user_id', '=', $userId);
      })->get(['topics.*']);
```

Mind that last solution will rely on your pivot data consistency. That said, if you can't be sure, that there are no redundant entries in `user_subscriptions` (eg. blog or user has been deleted but the pivot entry remains), then you need to further join `users` as well.

Comment: The first one worked (though I havn't tried others). Is there any way I can order topics by create_date for pagination?

Comment: Sure, just add `orderBy` in the closure.

Comment: ok, also oen last question. Is it possible to move the queries to the model? Or Eloquent queries can only be called in controllers?

Comment: Call it wherever you like, there's no **only**. Read about SOLID if you like to learn principles making your code better for you as well as for the others.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to laravel and I don't have the possibility of test this, but I had a similar need and solved it with something like this:

```
    DB::Query('topics')->join('blogs', 'blogs.id', '=', 'topics.blog_id')
    ->join('blog_subscriptions', 'blogs.id', '=', 'blog_subscriptions.blog_id')
    ->select('name.id','table.email')
    ->where('blog_subscriptions.user_id', '=', $user_id);
```